# Sorting names according to last name in java

Tags: java

I have written a Code as follows using Comparator to sort according to last name:

```
class Order{

    private static ArrayList<String> personlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator iter1 = personlist.iterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter1.next());
    }
    Collections.sort(personlist, new LastnameComparator());
    Iterator iter2 = personlist.iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter2.next());
    }
}

class String implements Comparable {
    String firstName, lastName;
    public String(String f, String l) {
        this.firstName = f;
        this.lastName = l;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "[ firstname=" + firstName + ",lastname=" + lastName + "]";
    }
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        String emp = (String) obj;
        int comp = firstName.compareTo(emp.getFirstName());
        return ((comp == 0) ? lastName.compareTo(emp.getLastName()) : comp);
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof String)) {
          return false;
        }
        String emp = (String) obj;
        return firstName.equals(emp.getFirstName()) &&                 lastName.equals(emp.getLastName());
    }
}
class LastnameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lastname1, String lastname2) {
        int lnameComp = lastname1.getLastName().compareTo(lastname2.getLastName());
        return ((lnameComp == 0) ? lastname1.getFirstName().compareTo(lastname2.getFirstName()) :
        lnameComp);     
    }
}
```

But this code does not work properly and gives me errors. personlist contains the following names:

```
John C. Shafer
Ariel Fuxman
Roberto J. Bayardo Jr.
Alexandre V. Evfimievski
Dmitri Asonov
Kristen LeFevre
```

and I want it to be displayed in the following way

```
Dmitri Asonov
Alexandre V. Evfimievski
Ariel Fuxman
Roberto J. Bayardo Jr.
Kristen LeFevre
John C. Shafer
```

What should I need to do in this code to fix it?Thank you.

Comment: _Don't make a class named `String`_.

Comment: Can you post what the errors are?

Comment: **What do the errors say**? Did you read them?

Comment: I wish I could up-vote @SLaks 1st comment 100 times!! Original poster, you have to change that class name ASAP.

Comment: It gives me error at main() saying cannot export for API and at various other places.

Comment: @user1320030: don't paraphrase the errors. You must post the *actual error message* in your question. You can edit your question and post this information at the bottom, and this is what I suggest that you do, but *after* renaming your String class.

Comment: It says it doesnt contain main class.and since I m working in an IDE it says exporting non public type through public API.

Comment: @user1320030: Don't *explain* what it says. Post the whole d**n message and let *us* do the explaining for ourselves...

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    String emp = (String) obj;
    int comp = firstName.compareTo(emp.getFirstName());
    return ((comp == 0) ? lastName.compareTo(emp.getLastName()) : comp);
}
```

Should be,

```
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    String emp = (String) obj;
    int comp = lastName.compareTo(emp.getLastName());
    return ((comp == 0) ? firstName.compareTo(emp.getFirstName()) : comp);
}
```

// you should also avoid name a class as String

Comment: Even if i change the name of class from String to something else it still gives me errors.

Comment: @user1320030: *what* errors? Please edit your question and *copy* and *paste* the *exact* message. Do not *describe* the message!

Comment: When I execute it,it gives me message saying class does not contain main method.The above code is just the part of my entire code.

Comment: @user1320030: are you going to post the exact messages or not? If not, you are wasting our time. From your last comment one realizes that there is a *lot* missing from your program - probably much more than we can reasonably help with here...

Comment: Is the above code correct to sort according to last name? I changed the name of the Class from String to something else..Is it so that coz of errors in this code the entire code is not working?? Or this code is perfectly fine??

Answer (score -2):

**CAUTION** If you do something like the following code, the world **WILL ACTUALLY END IN SECONDS**!
Please don't blame me, i warned you.

Just use normal `String`s and use a custom Comparator like this:

```
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String[] o1Data = o1.split(" ");
        String[] o2Data = o2.split(" ");
        String o1Last = o1Data[o1Data.length-1];
        String o2Last = o2Data[o2Data.length-1];
        return o1Last.compareTo(o2Last);
    }
}
```

Just extracts the last part of the names, and compares them.

Comment: what an ugly (and anti-OOP) solution.

Comment: Agree -- a terrible answer.

Comment: Sigh, why-oh-why do people insist on deleting incorrect posts? Deletion is for spam, non-answers and such. If it is a bad answer just downvote the thing! -1, BTW.

Comment: what is your problem guys, if he/she wants to do it with Strings, then here is the solution :D

Comment: @bali182: 1. the OP created their own class, that is *not* the same as a single string. 2. Letting "solutions" like this go unpunished only helps them propagate to the ignorant. As a TA I saw enough of such "solutions" *without* having the students get ideas from SO...

Comment: I might let such an answer go if it was surrounded with a whole bunch of If-you-do-this-the-world-will-end disclaimers, but not like this...

Comment: No one said that "the world will end". Rather we just said that this is a bad answer, and in fact that is what it is.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I saw *exactly* this kind of "design" in a bit of credit-card processing code recently. It would break *horribly* (and I do mean *horribly*) when someone had a middle name...

Comment: @thkala, Your experience doesn't justify this answer. It's just plain bad. This is an answer for the sake of an answer. You now have my downvote too.

Comment: @bali182: good enough, although I would also explain in a couple of sentences *why* it is a bad idea... -(-1) :-)